# Installed JsZip but its not working by grunt

Tags: node.js, git, npm, jszip

I used https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ on my local machine and update all dependency by npm and used command `grunt connect` but this only showing web server started but on this url its not working.

```
$ grunt connect
Running "connect:server" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9999

Done, without errors.
```

even i have tested the app there is no error,
can anyone let me know how to get such type of projects from git-hub and run locally by npm or composer/bower.

Comment: Without more information, we can't know what's going on. Edit your question with the output of `grunt connect --verbose`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used simple javascript instead of going with NodeJs and here my code is : 
[Here is Gist Code you can run.](https://gist.github.com/ManishLSN/491e738864fa976970565ca14a0252a1#file-read-local-file-api-html)